# Wrong Parameters are passed

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a a list control and a a ViewModel. I try to pass the selectedItems to the View Model if the tapped event is raised.

I can compile this code:

View:

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllMedicines}"
              SelectionMode="Multiple"
              Name="MedicineList" >
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=MedicineList}"/>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ListView>
```

ViewModel Command:

```
        SelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<IList>(
            items => {
                SelectedMedicines = (List<Medicine>) items;
            });
```

But if I tap on a item in the list I get this error message

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs' to type 'System.Collections.IList'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a converter and react to SelectionChanged event (or tapped as you do it at the moment, but as SelectedItems is something you want, you might want to think about that).

So you would set it up like this:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                                  InputConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=MedicineList}"
                                  InputConverter="{StaticResource SelectionChangedConverter}"/>
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

And the converter would simply be taking the ListView and passing the SelectedItems to your command:

```
public class SelectionChangedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var listView = parameter as ListView;

        return listView.SelectedItems;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Of course, the converter needs to be defined as a static resource somewhere:

```
<local:SelectionChangedConverter x:Key="SelectionChangedConverter" />
```

Comment: I just noticed that this will give me a com object and won't come to my command. If I parse it it get null.